# Cross-Selecting XML elements

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml document which is formatted like this:

```
<wsc>
    <entries>
        <id>1</id>
    </entries>
    <entries2keywords>
        <entryId>1</entryId>
        <keywordId>1</keywordId>
    </entries2keywords>
    <entries2keywords>
        <entryId>1</entryId>
        <keywordId>2</keywordId>
    </entries2keywords>
    <keywords>
        <id>1</id>
        <keyword>kw1</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <keywords>
        <id>2</id>
        <keyword>kw2</keyword>
    </keywords>
</wsc>
```

I'm trying to parse it so I can store all the keywords that belong to an  Element. So far I'm traversing all entries2keywords and looking for a matching entryId using this xpath expression:

```
//entries2keywords[entryId='1']/keywordId
```

Which returns the keywordId fine.

However, I'm looking for a way to select the actual keyword right away, so something like this (pseudocode):

```
//keywords[contains (id, //entries2keywords[entryId='1']/keywordId) ]/keyword
```

I realize it's badly formatted XML, but unfortunately I can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your peseudocode I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
//keywords[id = //entries2keywords[entryId='1']/keywordId ]/keyword
```